# How to synchronize Session and Form Authentication timeouts in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, session, form-authentication

In my `MVC 5` application Session expires before Form Authentication timeout.

I want to synchronize both Session and Form Authentication timeout.

1. How can I do this?
2. Should I logout the current user if Session expires? If yes then how?